# Telegram bot channel updates

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, lua-telegram-bot

How to recieve messages by bot inside the channel?
the method

> https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/getUpdates

Shows only a private bot chat updates.

Comment: Disable privacy mode. Talk to [BotFather](https://telegram.me/BotFather).

Comment: I'm talking about channels not about group chats.

Comment: Well, the bot does not get any channel updates.